# How do you deal with both percentage- and pixel-based sizes in one element in CSS?

Tags: css, xhtml

Specifically, I am referring to a situation where you need to have a total width of say 100% on a DIV, but a 10 pixel padding and 1 pixel border. (And don't rely on the browser automatically setting it to that width — say it's floated left for instance.)

Is there any simple way to accomplish this without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to set this on one element that works with the currently major browsers.

You could use 2 nested `div`s. Set the `100%` width on the outher `div`, and set the padding and border on the inner `div`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it wasn't possible with just one, but I wanted to make sure. I'll stick with nested DIVs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `box-sizing: border-box` you can set `width: 100%; border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;` and the total of the width, border, margin, and padding will be what is specified for the width. [Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing)

EDIT: True, browser support is a bit limited. FF 3.5 and Safari 4 support it, not sure about IE8 or Chrome.

Comment: Chrome and Safari are both Webkit--so generally speaking (CSS), they are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

That's only possible with CSS 3.

Comment: I presume you mean "That's *only* possible with CSS3": http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc

Answer (score 0):

What about the following solution?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">   
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">     
    <head>      
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
        <title>Content with Menu</title>         
    <style type="text/css">
      .content .outer{
        width:100%;
        border:1px solid black;
        background-color:green;
      }
      .content .inner{
        margin-left:10px;
        margin-right:10px;
        background-color:red;
      }
    </style>          
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div class="content">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">  
          <p>Hi!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update**
OK, doesn't accomplish what you are talking about with just one element.